# PubSub to BigQuery Subscription : not working

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-pubsub

## Avro Schema

```
{
  "namespace": "com.x.y.z.model",
  "name": "XYZDataPoint",
  "type" : "record",
  "fields" : [
    {
      "name" : "id",
      "type" : "string"
    },
    {
      "name" : "name",
      "type" : "string"
    },
    {
      "name" : "created_at",
      "type" : { "type": "long", "logicalType": "timestamp-micros" }
    }
  ]
}
```

### BigQuery Schema

```
[
  {
    "name" : "id",
    "type" : "string",
    "mode" : "NULLABLE"
  },
  {
    "name" : "name",
    "type" : "string",
    "mode" : "NULLABLE"
  },
  {
    "name" : "created_at",
    "type": "TIMESTAMP",
    "mode" : "NULLABLE"
  }
]
```

I created PubSub to BigQuery Subscription with above schemas and configured deadletter queue as well.

### Problem 1

When I am publishing messages, they are ending up in deadletter topic and not showing up in BigQuery.

#### From Deadletter Subscription My message looks like

```
{"id":"dddckdkc416-49a9-4cdnac-aa48-b07d8ckdsnaac2","name":"INITIATED","created_at":1693435133390}
```

### EDIT 1

I have one other similar PubSub to BQ Subscription where messages are landing fine up to BQ and AVRO/BQ Schema are similar.

#### Avro Schema

```
{
  "namespace": "com.x.y.z.model",
  "name": "XYZStatusDataPoint",
  "type" : "record",
  "fields" : [
    {
      "name" : "id",
      "type" : "string"
    },
    {
      "name" : "status",
      "type" : "string"
    },
    {
      "name" : "xyz_status",
      "type" : "string"
    },
    {
      "name" : "date",
      "type" : { "type": "long", "logicalType": "timestamp-micros" }
    }
  ]
}
```

#### BQ Schema

```
[
  {
    "name" : "id",
    "type" : "string",
    "mode" : "NULLABLE"
  },
  {
    "name" : "status",
    "type" : "string",
    "mode" : "NULLABLE"
  },
  {
    "name" : "xyz_status",
    "type" : "string",
    "mode" : "NULLABLE"
  },
  {
    "name" : "date",
    "type" : "TIMESTAMP",
    "mode" : "NULLABLE"
  }
]
```

#### Problem 2

However in this subscription on BQ side, date is not coming correctly. It is coming as `1970-01-20 14:23:55.133390 UTC`

Comment: This may be caused by an incorrect BigQuery schema. Put your input data into [this useful tool](https://transform.tools/json-to-big-query) and check it matches.

Comment: Okay for last column, tool is showing it should be Integer but I do have exact similar one more schema where messages are landing fine to BQ. I have added EDITs in the question.

Comment: Are you using any sort of Python code in your pipeline? Apache Beam Python SDK has a really frustrating bug when translating TIMESTAMP between schemas.

Comment: I am doing it in java. I have used AVRO plugin to generate POJOs from AVRO schemas mentioned in the question and then I created objects from POJO classes and published messages to pubsub.

Comment: For conversions between schema types, one should use the [schema compatibility information](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/bigquery#schema_compatibility) provided in the documentation. The Avro `timestamp-micros` logical type is compatible  with the `TIMESTAMP` type. The JSON-to-BigQuery transform tool likely does not account for this.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your timestamps are in milliseconds, not microseconds. This is why the time looks so small: the values passed in should be 1000x what they are.

I was able to insert messages into a BigQuery table using the exact Avro and BigQuery schemas you have (with the timestamps appearing to be from the 1970s), so there may be something deeper going on there. To investigate that, you should put in a support case.